# Android Studio - how do I call a method which references a drawable?

Tags: java, image, android-studio, resources

This is very much a noob question.

With the benefit of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32797295/how-to-remove-blank-space-around-an-image-in-android) answer from a different question, I have created a class which theoretically takes a BMP image and resizes it to the size of the image, rather than the (blank) background.

However, I can't work out how to run the class and reference an image which is saved as a drawable.

I've tried

```
package com.example.trimmer_test;
import android.media.Image;
public class Activity_main {
"@drawable/imagename"
}
```

After some searching, I thought that I had to use the getResource method to import the image, so I tried

```
package com.example.trimmer_test;
import android.media.Image;
public class Activity_main {
Activity_main.getResource("@drawable/imagename")
}
```

But this brings up a "cannot resolve symbol 'getResource'" error.

I've tried what feels like a million variants of this and can't figure it out.

Apologies for what I imagine is a basic question, but I have searched thoroughly and can't find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out.

ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.your_image_name)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I get error "cannot resolve symbol "ContextCompat"

Comment: [Google dev docs for ContextCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html)
You can also use getContext() instead.